# Уменьшить размер динамического массива несколько раз

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Нужно уменьшить размер массива

```
int size_a = 10;
int *a = new int[size_a];
```

Если нужно уменьшить один раз, то всё понятно: создаём ещё один массив, копируем элементы, старый удаляем

```
int size_b=size_a-1;
int *b = new int[size_b];
for (i=0;i<=size_b;i++)
  b[i]=a[i];
delete[] a;
```

А если, например, уменьшать нужно последовательно в теле цикла большое количество раз, то как поступить?

Comment: Лучше возьмите `std::vector`, тогда достаточно будет сделать `resize()`, `shrink_to_fit()`.

Answer (score 2):

Много раз перераспределять память и копировать элементы ни к чему. Вместо этого завести переменную, содержащую размер активной области, и уменьшать её.

А вот когда она, например, станет 1/2 или 1/4 от реального размера, тогда уже можно и выполнить реальное изменение размера.

Подобная тактика применяется и при расширении массива - сразу выделяется память с запасом, например, в полтора или два раза, и большую часть времени просто инкрементируется переменная, отвечающая за размер.

Answer (score 0):

создать динамический массив, означает занять  определенное количество байтов в свободной области памяти для некоторой цели. Мы  можем  освобождать память и занять другую или  просто  использовать нужное нам количество размера  массива:

```
template <class T>
T* resize(T*& p, const size_t sz)
{
    p += sz;
    return p;
}
int main()
{        
    char* p = new char[27], *q = p;
    // инициализируем символами ( допустим из альфовита)
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        *q++ = 'a' + i;
    q = p;
    for (int i = 2; i < 26; i *= 2) {
        std::cout << strlen(q) << std::endl;
        q = p;
        q = resize(q, i);
        // таким образом  не использую первые i байтов
    }        
    return 0;
}
```